# Large HTML Form - User Experience and Accessibility

Tags: php, html, css, forms, accessibility

i have a large form with a lot of fields. I used fieldset on it. How could I create a better experience to user/accessibility with this large form?
I think about split it. What do you think about it?

Comment: I think "I wonder what he is talking about, since I can't see what he can see."  More info please.

Comment: Please post a live example, a description and possibly a screenshot of exactly what you want your form to look like and some HTML and CSS for us to see, help us to help you. :)

Comment: Do One th ing Thomas Take the snap shot upload it in any free hosting site attach its url into ur SO editor and let us ssee for what type of form u r talking about before ur question gets DOWNVOTED B QUICK People are craving for DOWNVOTING  here.. They Enjoy DOWNVOTING..:)

Comment: @Parth: please go to disney.com or india.com.

Answer (score 2):

Don't re-invent the wheel and confuse the user. Keep it simple. You could break the form down into separate parts, either into separate steps or pages and even with a progress indicator to keep the user informed of where they are.

Form design patterns:

http://patterntap.com/tap/collection/forms

Comment: hmm U seems to be an Interpreter... :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to answer this if I knew a little bit more about the form and what kinds of users you want to be accessible for (ie - you would want to use different techniques if you are trying to be accessible for seniors than you would use if you want to be fully accessible for sight impaired users).  Rbaker gave you a tremendous answer and I encourage you to follow his advice/read the link he provided.

However, I would like to add one thing.  There is no rule that says that a form has to appear on one page.  There is also no rule that says that a 'form' cannot consist of a number of individual questions.  Depending on who you want to be able to use your form, a system flow like:

Do you accept our privacy policy? (Click 'yes'/'no)
What is your full name? (Click 'ok')
Would you like to register? (Click 'yes'/no')

You wouldn't have to refresh the page after each question, but if you gave users some idea of how close they are to being finished the form, an individual question approach might be less intimidating and more accessible for your users.

Finally, be proud of yourself for being concerned with accessibility!  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

i think better if you can post screenshot of that form. from my experience you can tryout some of the steps
1. Keep only fields which you need for uyour system rest take out.
2. Divide into different section
3. if needed can have accordion kind of panels
4. please have proper feedback system, better if you can prompt feedback while filling the form itself instead of waiting for submit or finish button.
5. from the visual, great to have white/gray kind of interface
6. have proper instruction for fields if needed
7. button with affordance

[artsrajesh](http://artsrajesh.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the information on this guys site. Most amazing I have seen anywhere on the net
http://www.lukew.com/presos/

there are many videos, pdf's, power points on form best practices

here is a good start on the site.
http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/EventApart_WebForms_120809.pdf
and here

http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html